# Defining a scope for JQuery variables, different js - single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 js on a single page. In one of the js I am doing `var jQuery = $.noConflict(true);` and after that using all the jQuery methods using jQuery object, like `jQuery("#div").hide();`

In another js, I am using the traditional $ variable & accessing the jQuery methods as `$("#div").hide();`

When on a page I use either of the 2 js', things work fine. However, when I include both, the $ in the second js seems to be overwritten by jQuery. for example, in js 2 I can no longer do `$("#div").hide()` but if I use jQuery instead of $, it works fine - `jQuery("#div").hide();`!

Why am I experimenting this is because the first div will be distributed to different websites as a plugin, and the second js could be the Jquery written by that website developer.

Please help me figure out where am I going wrong..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to use a pattern that plugin authors employ.

```
(function($) {

    // Use $ safely within the function

})(jQuery); // Passes in jQuery object
```

This is function is created and invoked immediately, and at the same time allows you to pass a variable into the scope of the function. Using this, you can carry on referring to $ in your code and not worry about overwriting it or conflicting.

The [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) advises this pattern

Comment: Okay. I create one function like this which is called at first. Now, I have multiple functions in that js, should I wrap each function like this or how do I take care of it?

Comment: Create just the one function, and treat that as the scope for all of your jQuery code for that particular page/application. It simply acts as a wrapper and you can add as many functions and variables inside as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `noConflict`, which releases jQuery's hold on `$`. Doesn't matter if it's in separate scripts, since it's the same global environment.

In the script where you want to use `$`, define that variable inside your `.ready()` handler.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('foo').bar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Files do not have scope, you dereferenced `$` with `noConflict` for your entire page. Anything

Comment: Would it work, if in my plugin I do var myJqueryVar = jQuery & then I use this variable to access jQuery methods? I am not deferencing $?